# Installation of Ubuntu 22.04.03 from pendrive is stuck

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, usb-drive

I'm trying to install ubuntu on an external ssd using a bootable pendrive.
I got to grub, but when I select try or install Ubuntu this is what I see and nothing seems to be changing.[a photo showing two ACPI errors and one x.509 certificate problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFHtP.jpg)
I'm completely new to Linux and have no idea how to select the ssd as the installation drive or if this is working in the background or stuck for good.
All help appreciated, thanks

Comment: I managed to get rid of the certificate error by reseting Setup Mode in UEFI. The installer is still stuck with just the two ACPI errors, which is weird as the certificate problem came after those two...